# Hello World CUDA produces no output

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'm a newbie using cuda. My version cuda is 10.02. I have a problem when I call hello world program.
This is the file hello.cu:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void mykernel(void) {
printf("GPU Hello World!\n");
}

int main(void) {
printf("CPU Hello World! \n");
mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
return 0;
}
```

But only receive the output:

```
CPU Hello World!
```

I am quite rookie on this, so, what can be happening? should I do something to call the kernel function?

Comment: Add `cudaDeviceSyncronize()` and you will get the second print too. Btw it would be a better hello world program if you would do proper [error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/7968757). And the title is misleading. You don't have compilation but runtime issues and also no error but an unexpected result.

Comment: Thanks for your support. But when I add cudaDeviceSyncronize() I receive an error:error: identifier "cudaDeviceSyncronize" is undefined

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00003051_00000000-8_hello.cpp1.ii".

Comment: Ohhh!!! I understand the problem. this is cudaDeviceSynchronize(); but you write: cudaDeviceSyncronize(). Thank you for your support!!! many thanks!

Comment: Yeah, just was about to write that. Sorry for the misspelling.

Comment: Question to the community: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12591765/7968757) answer the question here and should this be flagged as a duplicate? I think the real answer is only in the comment below the linked answer. I generally think that this is a somewhat common problem which may needs its own answer.

Comment: Yes I think the same thing.